# Is there a way I can use javascript to change the hidden value (in css) of a component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout

I have
`<div class="notification">`
whose visibility is set to hidden (in CSS) and
`<button>`.

I want to:

1. On button click, switch the visibility of the `div` from `hidden` to `visible`
2. After 5 seconds, switch the visibility of the `div` back to `hidden`

I can only use JS, HTML, and CSS (no jquery)

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried please? This will help us answer your question faster :)

Comment: You need to be more specific with where you're stuck, not just post a list of requirements. I would start by searching for "change css with JavaScript" if you need help getting started.

Comment: Have you try to use these: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createattribute.asp / https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an eventlistener on the button which adds a extra class to your div and starts a timeIntervall at which the class is removed. Add at your CSS a new rule that makes the DIV visible if both classes are present.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    let div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    div.classList.add('visible');
    setTimeout(function(){
        div.classList.remove('visible');
    }, 5000);
})
```

```css
.notification {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.notification.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id='myDiv' class="notification">Notification</div>
<button id='btn'>Show Div</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess is this you're looking for

```js
btn.onclick = () => {
  notification.style.visibility = 'visible';
      setTimeout(()=>{
        notification.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    },5000)
}
```

```css
#notification {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="notification">notification</div>
<button id="btn">show</button>
```